# Remote tar.gz with sql run local server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tar.gz with a full mysql database update that I can access via ftp.

This tar.gz updates daily and I would like to create a php and/or mysql connection to that ftp account that would allow me to run that large sql query on my local mysql server.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you want to do this from a unix box of some kind...)

Throw this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget                        \
    -O -                    \
    --ftp-user=username     \
    --ftp-password=password \
    "ftp://wherever/whatever.tar.gz" | tar xzOf - | mysql --user=whoever --password=secret dbname
```

in a file (`update-db.sh` for example) then `chmod` it:

```
chmod 755 update-db.sh
```

then you can just:

```
./update-db.sh
```

whenever you want to download the update.  Or you can throw it into a cron job (`man crontab`).

**Edit:** Added the `O` flag to `tar` so that it extracts to stdout.

Comment: and could I run the tar.gz sql source into my mysql server at the same time? how?

Comment: sorry I didnt read the full script... thanks a lot gona try it

Comment: what does ": bad interpreter: No such file or directoryin/bash" mean??? any ideas?

Comment: Most likely you have carriage returns (\r) in the file instead of just newlines (\n)

Comment: @Bright, The problem with your script is that you're running mysql on the output of tar.  tar extracts files, so you need to make a temporary directory and run mysql on all e.g. *.sql files.

Comment: got it... line endings in windows

Comment: @Hugo: see my minor update (change xzf to xzOf in the call to tar)

Comment: changed it still get an error 
Resolving  ... failed: Name or service not known.
line 4: -O: command not found

Comment: my bad. copy paste didnt work that good and had to solve the line endings to linux and the extra spaces into tabs... now I only have a problem with permissions for the database... but I think I am on the right track...

Answer (score 1):

First of all PHP supports reading from FTP out of the box, just use fopen with specified ftp protocol like so

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
?>
```

then you will need to unzip the archive. Here [File_Archive](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Archive) from Pear repository will come very handy

Comment: Thats a start.
But is there a way to run the full sql without extracting?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway go with Sean's solution I haven't realized that you will be using cron